# Json String Output is roundoff the value

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I have a kotlin function which get the value from JSON response but the entries in the below code is rounding the number instead of getting double or orginal JSON value. I changed the .tofloat to .toDouble in the code but I am getting error in the code. Any help is appreciated.

**Input**

```
var    test= "[{"date":"2018-12-12","amount":"10.65"}
```

**JSON Code**

```
    val jsonStringArray = test.toString()
    val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    val labels = ArrayList<String>()
    val arr = JSONArray(jsonStringArray)
    for (i in 0 until arr.length()) {
        entries.add(BarEntry(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("amount").toFloat(), i))
        labels.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"))
    }
  println("Entries value" + entries)
                val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Test")
                val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
                barChart.data = data 
                barChart.setValueTextSize(10f)
                **Chart is Rounding off the value in the display**
```

**Output Result**
10.7

**Output Expected**
10.65

Comment: in json response amount is string not an int. u can get it like this getJSONObject(i).getString("amount"); no need to convert it in  float

Comment: The chart is rounding off the value but I am not sure, how to display the real value.

Comment: try this arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("amount").toDouble()

Answer (score 1):

I think it gives an exact string as like in the `JSON`

```
String str_amount = getJSONObject(i).getString("amount");
```

Comment: It's rounding the value to close decimal like 10.65 to10.7

Comment: getJSONObject(i).getString("amount"); .. if you use this it will gives exact.. from the JSON chaeck json omce if you are getting ..correct or not..

Comment: I updated the remaining code as well. Still its showing the data in the graph to round off value like 10.56 to 10.6. I need to get the value in the graph as it.

Comment: I have already updated the code something is happening in the chart, I think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185589/discussion-between-satyan-android-and-joshva-jo).

Answer (score 0):

Try this round off two decimal values of your JSON Object value

**Answer 1 :**

```
val amountValue:Double = getJSONObject(i).getString("amount").toDouble()
val twoDigitValue:Double = String.format("%.2f", amountValue).toDouble()
```

**Answer 2 :**

```
val amountValue:Double = getJSONObject(i).getString("amount").toDouble()
val twoDigitValue:Double = Math.round(amountValue * 100.0) / 100.0
```